# Is it possible to render an HTML in a word document

Tags: c#

I was trying to render the HTML Code in Word. 
As the emails in outlook 2007 uses Word rendering techniques but i am trying to render the HTML into word so that it can easily be viewed in the Outlook 2007.

Comment: @ASP - are you able to edit your question, and fill in any details around: what you've tried so far, what the end goal is, and what technologies you're using to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered formatting and saving your HTML in a standards-compliant way? This will help:

- promote reuse of those documents in other programs/consumers
- the developer by not having to twist/mangle their HTML output to conform to some output by Office products. I'm thinking here that you're anticipating writing HTML that would mimick Word's HTML output.

Know also that [Office 2007 products are fully capable of rendering CSS markup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx).

I am not suggesting that Outlook and Word do not read or deal in non-standard HTML, but rather, consider that they are ABLE to read standard HTML.

**So the answer is: don't worry about it.** All the Office products will read/consume:

- [HTML 4](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_quick.asp)
- [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML)
- XML documents
- most everything else you throw at it.

Comment: I am talking about Outlook 2007 that have Word Rendering technique to view the document. But initially it is having a IE and word rendering in it.
so basically when i send the mail having HTML than it uses word rendering and failed to support the Viewing of data in Outlook 2007.

So i was trying to convert the HTML into word so that outlook will easily show the document directly.